# findViewById in different layout (cannot find BottomNavigationView)

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I'm doing an app so when you click on a login button, it will then display a screen with a bottom menu. But I'm having problems with setting the listener to the items in the menu. The problem is when I try to use findViewById to find my BottomNavigationView it will look for it in my activity_main instead of the fragment (welcome_fragment) where I have put it, because I only want it to show when someone has logged in. And therefore I will get null as the BottomNavigationView.

I have tried setting setContentView(R.layout.welcome_fragment) in my method "welcomePage", which does make it so that so that it will find it and it won't be null. However this results in a lot of other errors such as
" No view found for id 0x7f080032 (com.example.MyAPP:id/container) for fragment WelcomePage{9547e9f #1 id=0x7f080032}", so I don't believe it to be the right way to go about it.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Login loggingIn= new Login();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, loggingIn).commit();
    }

     //When button is pressed we get into this function
     public void finishProcess(){

        WelcomePage wp = new WelcomePage();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, wp).commit();


        try {
         //Here is where I get null, because we are looking in activity_main
         BottomNavigationView bottomNav=findViewById(R.id.bottomnavigate);
         bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuListener);}
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }}

    //Have tried this one and it works fine
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener menuListener 
     = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {...}
}
```

Here is my WelcomeFragment:

```
    public class WelcomePage extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, container, false)}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Here is my layout to the welcome_fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WelcomePage"
    android:background="@drawable/welcomegradient">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/showing_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomnavigate">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomnavigate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/mymenu"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

As I mentioned earlier the problem is that findViewById can't find the BottomNavigationView because it is looking in the activity_main instead of welcome_fragment and I don't want to put my menu in activity_main because I only want to display it when a user has logged in. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: and what you are talking about toggling the visibility.. you can do it as `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` based on your condition

Comment: you are including it in activity class part so it will look in activity layout, while your bottomnavigation is in fragment part. so but obvious it will look in that activity part

Comment: Okay, how do I fix it?  @Sam

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work.
WelcomePage

```
public class WelcomePage extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, container, false);

        //Have tried this one and it works fine
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener menuListener 
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {...}

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomnavigate);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuListener);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private FragmentManager fm;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
       Login loggingIn= new Login();
       fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, loggingIn).commit();
   }

   //When button is pressed we get into this function
   public void finishProcess() {

        WelcomePage wp = new WelcomePage();
        fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, wp).commit();
    }
}
```